# Batch file to remove substring from list of files

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

Given a list of files (50,000 files)

```
1_data.csv
2_data.csv
3_data.csv

...
```

How would you rename them to 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv ... using a Batch file?

Comment: Do you really mean in dos, or just in the command prompt in windows?

Comment: Command prompt in Windows (as per cmd.exe). I just wrote DOS to be concise.

Comment: If you write »DOS« you're not being concise, you're being wrong. The syntax differs greatly between DOS' `command.com` and the Windows Command Processor (`cmd.exe`). If you're looking for a solution in the latter language you do people answering a favor by stating that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to use a batch file, this works on my machine (though not tested with 50000 files):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%i IN ('dir /b %~dp0*.csv') DO (
    ren %%i_data.csv %%i.csv
)
```